# How to upload Image from react native app to wordpress api?

Tags: wordpress, react-native

I want to upload an Image from my react-native app to WordPress backend through a custom API. I want to use that image as a gravatar for the user who is a WordPress user. Can someone give me a lead on this?
I also want to know how we will make a post request with an image and how to make an endpoint for changing the profile picture of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a directory for both of our apps to live in
Creating a new React Native app
Installing the react-native-image-picker library
Linking the native dependencies of react-native-image-picker

In your terminal, run the following:

```
$ mkdir image-upload-example
$ cd image-upload-example
$ react-native init mobile
$ cd mobile
$ npm install --save react-native-image-picker
$ react-native link react-native-image-picker
```

You then have to enable the necessary permissions in both the iOS and Android apps associated with your React Native app.

On iOS, this takes place in `mobile/ios/mobile/Info.plist`, and you’ll want to add:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>`
<string>For choosing a photo.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>For taking a photo.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>For saving a photo.</string>
```

On Android, you’ll want to find the AndroidManifest.xml file a few directories down in mobile/android and add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can then run react-native run-ios or react-native run-android, resulting in something similar.